# How should I embed/include Enterprise Architect UML diagrams in MS PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: uml, powerpoint, enterprise-architect

**Setup**

I am using [Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect Professional edition 7.5](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) and MS PowerPoint.

**Problem**

I have various audiences for presentations requiring display in MS PowerPoint -- ranging from managers to developers, whose depth of technical knowledge and requirements for knowledge varies.

**Question**

I have tried various settings for fonts, colors, and so on, but displaying a diagram with any level of detail (even simple class diagrams).  These diagrams are very difficult to fit into a PowerPoint slide and render well when using a projector or a Live Meeting.

Am I on the wrong path here, or is there a better/correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest omitting everything what is unnecessary for given slide from the diagram before export. The problem with slides is, that you cannot work with enough space, attention and also the time is often limited. The best way to get around this is to stay focused as much as it gets. Another way you might try could be splitting the diagram and showing a small rectangle of it at the time, however this can be confusing especially when your diagram is not layed out well. Third option which comes in mind is presenting using the tool with zoom - this can enable quick jumps, but will be distracting as you will navigate the diagram.

Comment: Agree with Gabriel wholeheartedly. You can also use custom animations to zoom in and out and/or highlight things. Also, and not to make your life more complex with even more software, you can consider using a tool like pptPlex: http://www.officelabs.com/projects/pptPlex/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also organize a slide show within the tool (which should alleviate some of the .jpeg/.gif/.png resolution issues that usually arise when you copy and paste diagrams directly into PowerPoint.

[Check This](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/modeling_tool_features/diagram_slideshow.htm)